# On key up or change event, fire Ajax to send data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried both keyup and change functions and here's why they don't do the trick. 
The user enters a voucher code and I want to send and ajax request which checks if the voucher exists in the database. I've tried:

```
$('#discount-voucher').keyup(function(event) {
    // Get the value
    let value = $(this).val()

    // Check if exists
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('get-voucher') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', code: value}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if (data == 'error') {
            $('span#voucher-error').text('Неавлиден ваучер')
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error")
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete")
    })
})
```

But those vouchers will be sent by email and let's say the user copy paste them. It will not work.
And with the change function the user has to click outside of the input or to press enter for the function to take effect and I don't want that neither I want a tip/hint which says "click outside the input ot press enter to check if the voucher is valid". So the things I need is something like the change function which takes effect without clicking or pressing enter

Comment: Why won't `keyup`/`keydown` work?

Comment: Because there are other ways to input values beside the keyboard. he says that in his question.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Ah, got it, thanks. Thought he meant copying/pasting *from* the form at first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a paste event, you can set multiple eventlisteners like following:

```
$('#discount-voucher').on('keyup paste change', function () {
      //Do something  . . . .
});
```

also you may need to throttle the ajax request so it doesn't get called too often by typing.

Comment: I've tried it but again I have to click outside the element or press enter

Comment: @TheAngelM97 You can add the events you need, like focusin and focusout.

Comment: The problem is when I copy paste the voucher again I have to click outside of the element for the function to activate
with the focusin I will focus the input before pasting the voucher, the function will activate but the value will be empty and then after I paste the voucher I will have to click outside the element again

Comment: Remove points between  keyup paste and change,: $('#discount-voucher').on('keyup paste change', function () {